# Editing CSV file in Emacs. Visualize first field with different color

Tags: csv, emacs, elisp

I am trying to simplify the editing of a CSV file in Emacs. I would like to hightlight the first field of each row/line in different font foreground color. For example

```
KEYWORD1,description,value
KEYWORD2,description,value
KEYWORD3,description,value
KEYWORD4,description,value
```

I would like to highlight `KEYWORD1`, `KEYWORD2`, `KEYWORD3`, and `KEYWORD4` in a different color. I tried to install `csv-mode` but it seems it does not offer this feature. I am using GNU Emacs 24.3.1 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming csv-mode is a normal mode (I did not have it installed), this should work out of the box:

```
(add-hook 'csv-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("^\\([^,]*\\)," 1 'font-lock-function-name-face)))))
```

Just replace `font-lock-function-name-face` with the face of your choice, if you don't like that particular color

Comment: Perfect! It also updates added lines immediately. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I experimented a little bit with text properties, and came up with

```
(defun csv-highlight-1 ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion 
    (beginning-of-buffer)
    (setq spos t)
    (while spos
      (setq spos (re-search-forward "^[^,]*," nil t))
      (when spos
        (let ((mod (buffer-modified-p)) (pos1 (line-beginning-position)) (pos2 (- spos 1)))
        (put-text-property pos1 pos2 'font-lock-face '(:foreground "red"))
        (put-text-property pos1 pos2 'front-sticky t)
        (set-buffer-modified-p mod))))))
```

It seems to work, but I have to call it manually each time I update the buffer. But maybe that is ok.